# Why does Chrome DevTools shows the same sizes of SVG elements with different stroke widths?

Tags: html, svg, google-chrome-devtools

For example, circle with `r="25"` and `stroke-width="1"`:

[image: Stroke = 1]

And circle with the same radius and `stroke-width="40"`:

[image: Stroke = 40]

Code of those examples:

```
<p style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
...............Text as ruler...............
</p>
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" stroke="black" fill="aqua" stroke-width="1"/>
  <!--and stroke-width="40"-->
</svg>
```

Why does Chrome DevTools show the same sizes of SVG elements with different stroke widths?

Comment: I assume the devtools calls some internal API that ignores strokes.